# Accessing protobuf from different project .Net

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to build out a large system using gRPC. I have a project where I define a .proto file. I create a second project that takes a reference to the first project. I want to be able to use a message defined in the first project's proto file in a message defined in the second project's proto file.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In these cases I always place the proto files in their own repository. For example if you are using git you then use the repository with definition files in both of your projects as a *submodule*.

In the end you will have three repositories:

1. Message definitions
2. Project A
3. Project B

Project A and B will refer to the Message definitions repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was/is my plan B. I was hoping that there was a way I could encapsulate project specific proto files in that specific project. and access them from the other projects. I will likely end up doing something like this in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59821705/9742876

In short, it's possible to do this if you add `ProtoRoot` attribute to your `<Protobuf />` section in the `.csproj` file. `ProtoRoot` changes the root folder where the `import` statement starts searching for `.proto` files, but check out the link above for more info.