# Importing .proto files from another project

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have several contract projects that contains different protobuf files, but some of the message types have the same message  type like

```protobuf
message user
{
  Address address = 1
}

message Address 
{
  ....
}
```

I have now created a shared project and added an Address.proto file to it only containing

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3"
option csharp_namespace = "shared.protos"
package AddressPackage
message Address {....}
```

My problem is to figure out how to import it into the protos in my different contract projects.
I have added the shared project as a reference, but everything else that I have tried from there has resultet in errors.

I know that I need to use `import` just haven't figured out how to write the string.

**Update**

I'm using gRPC.tools nuget and all .proto files is set to protobuf compiler both

The files structure is as following

User.Contracts project

- Protos
  -- User.proto
  Shared project
- Protos
  -- Address.proto

both projects is in it's own folder and those folders are placed next to each other.

in the shared project it says

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Protos\Address.proto" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\Address.proto">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

and in the user.contract is says

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Protos\User.proto" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\User.proto" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using gRPC.tools for this? If so: what does the relevant csproj pieces look like for the .proto files? Or are you using protoc directly? Or ..? And: what is the folder structure of the various files, relative to the project root?

Comment: @MarcGravell please see the update

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `ProtoRoot="whatever"` optional argument on `<Protobuf>`, which is similar to the include arg on protoc - try `<Protobuf ProtoRoot="Protos" ... >` ?

Answer (score 11):

You can do so by adding the `ProtoRoot` attribute to the `<Protobuf />` section in your `.csproj` file.

Let's say you have a `.proto` file in project A:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Project.A";
import "ProjectB/<path>/Engine.proto"

message Car {
    Engine engine = 1;
    ...
}
```

In project B you have:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "Project.B";

message Engine {
    ...
}
```

As you can see, in `car.proto` we used an import statement to a `.proto` file from another project. In order to successfully import this file, we need to add `ProtoRoot` to the `<Protobuf />` section in the `.csproj` file of the project A:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="ProjectA/<path>/car.proto" Link="<path>/car.proto" ProtoRoot=".." />
</ItemGroup>
```

`<path>` is equivalent to your folder structure within your .NET project. `ProtoRoot` needs to be set to the directory where import declarations in the `.proto` files are looking for files. In this case, it's the parent folder which contains two subfolders with project A and project B.

More interesting stuff can be found here:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md

Comment: This didn't help me. I see the proto from Project B as a link inside Project A, but when importing in a proto file in Project A, I get file not found error.

Comment: how would this look like when importing protos from nuget?

Answer (score 8):

This is quite more complicated than I've foreseen due the amounts of "moving parts" plus the documentation is somehow outdated and at the moment of writing some attributes appears to behave differently from the post above.

Basically in the car example above, using Visual Studio 2022 you should end up with this
[image]

to obtain this, ProjA needs a quite of work, the interesting bits appers to be

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="../ProjB/ProjB.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup> 
   <Protobuf Include="..\ProjB\Protos\engine.proto" GrpcServices="None" ProtoCompile="False">
      <Link>ProjB\Protos\engine.proto</Link>      
   </Protobuf>  
   <Protobuf Include="../ProjA/Protos/car.proto" Link="Protos/car.Proto" GrpcServices="None" ProtoRoot=".." />
</ItemGroup>
```

Please note that the important part is, as Yury Yatskov and Ivan Ivković said, to set the `ProtoRoot=".."` but it is mandatory that **the path specified in ProtoRoot is a prefix of the path in the Include** attribute.
**Note**:

- `ProtoRoot` is relative to the .csproj file
- `Import` is relative to the .csproj file *BUT* need to have `ProtoRoot` as prefix, so basically one level up and then again enter inside the ProjA again

this way the `include` statement in `car.proto` will be able to start from the path specified in `ProtoRoot` for searching for the .proto files to include

** ProjA/Protos/car.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "ProjB/Protos/Engine.proto";

option csharp_namespace = "ProjA";

package ProjA;

message Car{
    ProjB.Engine engine = 1;
    string licensePlate = 2;
}
```

** ProjB/Protos/engine.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "ProjB";

package ProjB;

message Engine{
    string name = 1;
}
```

Again note that of course you will need to reference Engine message using its package so `ProjB.Engine`

Finally, this allows to include the ProjB as a normal reference of the ProjA

[image]

but **PAY ATTENTION** to set `Compile Protobuf` option to No (as you can see in the .csproj reported above) otherwise there will be class name conflicts as both projects will redefine the same "Engine" class.

`grpc stub classes` attributes seems to not play a big role here, it is more interesting if the .proto contains a service definition, I think.

Answer (score 6):

In your projects, specify Protobuf with Include and ProtoRoot which should contain the path to a shared project with proto-files like

```s-code
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\NameSharedProject\Protos\address.proto" ProtoRoot="..\NameSharedProject" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then, after building in each project, you will have class files created in the folder "\obj\Debug\net5.0\Protos".

Comment: The class is created, but I cannot import it in my proto files, compiler says file not found

Comment: John Demetriou, if you have a problem, please show your projects.

Comment: I decided to use nuget packages instead. I put my protos in a nuget package, and whoever wants them, references the nuget package

Comment: This is a good approach to put into a nuget package.
There is also some good material on gRPC and .proto from Mehmet Özkaya.
https://medium.com/aspnetrun/using-grpc-in-microservices-for-building-a-high-performance-interservice-communication-with-net-5-11f3e5fa0e9d
https://github.com/aspnetrun/run-aspnet-grpc

Answer (score 3):

I've resolved this issue using the documentation available at the following url [Protocol Buffers/gRPC Codegen Integration Into .NET Build](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md#reference).

**Long story shorts**: the Xml attribute `AdditionalImportDirs="A_DIR_WITH_PROTOS"` for xml item `Project\ItemGroup\Protobuf` did the trick.

## Car/engine example

Referring to car engine example above in **ProjA** you should have

```xml
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="../ProjB/ProjB.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup> 
   <Protobuf Include="../ProjB/Protos/engine.proto" GrpcServices="None" ProtoCompile="False" Link="ProjB\Protos\engine.proto"/>  
   <Protobuf Include="../ProjA/Protos/car.proto" AdditionalImportDirs="../ProjB" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then, when protobuffer compiler process `car.proto` file wil look inside folder `../ProjB/Protos` to find `engine`.
This imply that, inside file **ProjA/Protos/car.proto**, you should import `engine` in the following way:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "Protos/Engine.proto"; // Because of 'AdditionalImportDirs="../ProjB"' you should specify here the remaining path from 'ProjB' to 'Engine.proto' that is 'Protos/Engine.proto'.

option csharp_namespace = "ProjA";

package ProjA;

message Car{
    ProjB.Engine engine = 1;
    string licensePlate = 2;
}
```

I've tried above code on Visual Studio 2022, dotnet 7.0 and Grpc.AspNetCore 2.52.0.

Answer (score 1):

Another option. It's easier not to use a shared project. The `.proto` file needs to be placed only in the service project and specified

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\address.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and in the project the client only needs to specify the link like this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="..\NameServerProject\Protos\address.proto" GrpcServices="Client">
        <Link>Protos\address.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

`ProtoRoot` can be missed.

Comment: Getting a file not found error when doing this method. What should the import look like in the proto file you're attempting to add the linked file to? Simply doing 'import "address.proto"; or 'import "Protos\address.proto"' as I would expect in this case seems to not work. The link is made correctly in my IDE to the file in question, and I can reference it in my C# code, but seemingly not from my .proto file.

Comment: In the service project, you need to add a proto file, then add the Protobuf element to the ItemGroup. Then you need to build the project.
After that, in the client's project, you need to add the Protobuf element to the ItemGroup and build the project. You also need to make sure that the path to the folder with the file is specified correctly. I use IDE VisualStudio 2019 last.

Answer (score 0):

I was using MicroServices Architecture and I wanted my message ProtoFiles should in SharedProto Project and Used them in different projects

Let's Say I have message Proto files in SharedProto

```
SharedProto
--Protos
----company_dto.proto
----branch_dto.proto
---- ...
```

Content of company_dto.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "SharedProto.Protos";

package sharedproto.protos;
// *** DTO
message CompanyDto {
  int32 Id = 1;
  string Code = 2;
  string Name = 3;
  string Logo = 4;
  string Website = 5;
}
```

Content of SharedProto.csproj

```
....
<ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\company_dto.proto" GrpcServices="None">
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\branch_dto.proto" GrpcServices="None">
</ItemGroup>
....
```

Project Organization where I have Services Protos

```
Organization
...
--Protos
----company_rpc.proto
----branch_rpc.proto
...
```

I want to import `comapany_dto.proto` (which is a part of SharedProto Project) into `comapany_rpc.proto` (Which is part of Organization Project). Let's have look at `.csproj` file because all trick lies here:

Content of Organization.csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SharedProto\SharedProto.csproj">
      <GlobalPropertiesToRemove></GlobalPropertiesToRemove>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- DTOs -->
    <Protobuf Include="..\SharedProto\Protos\company_dto.proto" ProtoRoot=".." GrpcServices="None" Link="Protos\company_dto.proto" />
    
    <Protobuf Include="Protos\company_rpc.proto" AdditionalImportDirs="../SharedProto" GrpcServices="Server" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you see above Organzation.csproj file, there are some really important points you need to understand to avoid `file not found error`  in case of import proto files from other projects.

`ProtoRoot=".."` and `Link="Protos\company_dto.proto"` after this, add this `AdditionalImportDirs="../SharedProto"` on that `<Protobuf Include=....` where you want to import your file. However after these setting you are able to import SharedProto file in your other projects in my case it was Organization project. Have a look

Content of company_rpc.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "Protos/company_dto.proto";

package organization.companyrpc;

// *** Rpc-Service

service CompanyRpcService {
  // Retrieve All
  rpc GetAllCompanies (google.protobuf.Empty) returns (GetCompanyListResponse){
    
  }
  ....

}
// Response: Retrieve All 
message GetCompanyListResponse {
  repeated sharedproto.protos.CompanyDto DtoRows = 1;
  string Message = 2;
}
```

If your see my `company_rpc.proto` file you will understand how I am importing it(`import "Protos/company_dto.proto";`) and how I am utilizing it (`sharedproto.protos.CompanyDto DtoRows`)

remember this `sharedproto.protos` came from a package name into company_dto.proto file

This above mention settings works for me in .net core grpc 2.60.0 and .net core 8