# Importing proto files from different directories

Tags: c#, visual-studio, grpc

I'm struggling writing the right configuration for grpc imports.

So the .net solution structure is like: 
*\Protos\Common\common.proto* 
*\Protos\Vehicle\car.proto* 
*\CarMicroservice*

Inside car.proto I have: `import "common.proto"`

What I want is the **generated grpc code to be inside the project** CarMicroservice. 
Inside CarMicroservice.csproj I have written the path to the protos:

```
<Protobuf Include="common.proto" ProtoRoot="..\Protos\Common\" />
<Protobuf Include="car.proto" ProtoRoot="..\Protos\Vehicle\" />
```

But getting error: 'common.proto' no such file or directory

The question is:
How do I correctly import common.proto inside the car.proto?

Note: I already looked at the similar issue, but couldn't make it work for my case 
[Importing .proto files from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422186/importing-proto-files-from-another-project/59821705#59821705)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using protobufs with .NET but, in my experience, correctly setting proto paths and includes is always challenging. Have you tried `ProtoRoot="..\Protos"` and `Include="Common/common.proto"` etc.? I think you'll need to revise your import to `import "Common/common.proto"` too. You may need to use absolute rather than relative (`..\Protos`) paths too.

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. I already solved the issue. But your comment is close to correct answer

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved the issue. Also @DazWilkin pointed it out.

1. You can't use relative paths in the `import`, so you should use absolute path of the project. In my case it was: `import "Common/common.proto"`
2. Use the project root for the location of proto files. So instead of `ProtoRoot="..\Protos\Common\"` use `ProtoRoot="../Protos/"` 
   Now comes the interesting part.
   For some reason when I used backslashes for the ProtoRoot path as `"..\Protos\` 
   I was getting errors as 'file not found'. So **don't** use the backslashes for paths.
   The final code in CarMicroservice.csproj is like the following:

```
<Protobuf Include="Common/common.proto" ProtoRoot="../Protos/" />
<Protobuf Include="Vehicle/car.proto" ProtoRoot="../Protos/" />
```

Comment: Maybe you can mark this as answer. So that it will help others to find solution quickly if they face similar issue.

Comment: Can't seem to get this same setup working. Still getting File not found error even though it's visibly linked in the file explorer and I can use the generated stubs in the c# code.

Comment: I have the same problem like @MatthewHeimlich ! error : File not found.

Comment: So the solution is not building? Can you share your code? What I noticed that, there're still warnings generated in Visual Studio, but the program works

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, there are two other ways to specify include directories for `protoc`.

First, there is a global property named `Protobuf_AdditionalImportsPath`. If you specify this property in your `.csproj`/`.fsproj`, it will be passed on to `protoc` for every `.proto` in that project. You can use it like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Protobuf_AdditionalImportsPath>../../my/other/directory</Protobuf_AdditionalImportsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There is also a `AdditionalImportDirs` property you can specify directly on `<Protobuf>` elements. This will likely only be valid for the `.proto`s you specify it on:

```
<Protobuf Include="MyProto.proto" Link="MyProto.proto" AdditionalImportDirs="../../my/other/directory" />
```

Keep in mind that in both cases, you can specify any directory you want, regardless of whether it is a parent of the `.proto` you're compiling.

Also keep in mind that the import path you specify in your `.proto` needs be relative to one of the import directories you specify.

Comment: If you need to specify multiple import directories, separate them with a semicolon, as seen on this page: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22878